# How to programatically know if an Azure Storage Table has changed?

Tags: azure, storage

I was wondering if there is any way to programatically know if a table in Azure Table Storage has changed and then what has changed in the table?

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. Your only option would be to go through all records in the table and see if the record changed based on the Timestamp property ([even though the official documentation advises you not to read the Timestamp property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx)).

Or have your code do the tracking each time an entity is added/updated/removed by writing this to an other table (an audit table).